# Is it possible to store data in browserify modules?

Tags: javascript, browserify, node-modules

I'd like to make a quick wrapper over $.ajax, which will essentially replicate the $.ajaxSetup functionality. The reason for this is that I want to only set defaults for certain actions, and not contaminate what other libraries will use $.ajax for.

the solution would look something like this ->

`$myAjax.defaults['headers'] = ... 
$myAjax.fetch({..}) -> will run an ajax command using new defaults`

I want to make $myAjax available through browserify

The question is, how could I store the defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, make a JSON file and just require it.

## data-file.json

```
{
  "data": "This is some data",
  "foobar": "more data"
}
```

## my-module.js

```
var myData = require('./data-file.json');
console.log(myData.data);   // => "This is some data"
console.log(myData.foobar); // => "more data"
```

Browserify can bundle JSON files.

Comment: Hey Sukima, what I would also like to do is to edit myData, while coding. i.e in one component, I might set myData.headers to x, and want all other components that use $myAjax afterwards to know that the headers is x. Do you have thoughts on this?

Comment: When it reads it's in memory so you can change it all you want (in code). If you want to save it back to the original source however, you will have to develop some mechanism to do so and way outside the scope of this question.

Comment: To clarify, Browserify bundles JavaScript code (and JSON which is valid JavaScript anyway). By nature this is volitile. If you want a JSON-like object to be non-volitile (save as persistent storage) then your don't want Browserfy but instead a server or localStorage as usual. I find including JSON in a Browserify bundle best for things like configs/db connection settings where the data editing is usually the developer running Browserify. If it is for application state the a regular Object will do and the JSON bundled is for setting the initial default values.